# Call Elastic APM Properties From Spring Boot Application Properties

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, properties, apm

I try to implement profile based application in Spring Boot and this works for Spring Boot clearly. But when I try to implement it for elastic-search APM, it doesn't work.

According to [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/configuration.html#configuration-dynamic): We can describe properties like with elastic.apm prefix:

```
elastic.apm.service_name=my-cool-service
elastic.apm.application_packages=org.example,org.another.example
elastic.apm.server_urls=http://localhost:8200
```

but it doesn't work. When I call it with elasticapm.properties, it works.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the method described here [disscuss-elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/java-agent-set-environment-programatically/226575), via ElasticApmAttacher#attach(map of properties).